# python tkinter read user input text label each letter separately

Tags: python, tkinter, label, encoder

Code runs but when I try to write something there is a notification in therminal:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users\", line 11, in getting_Text
    if text[0] == 'a' :
  File "C:\Users", line 1643, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

And also: Do I have to put all alphabet to all characerts like
`if user[0]== "a"`
`if user[0]== "b"`
etc
and do I have to do it to like thousands of characters like [0] then [1]... [100]

```
import tkinter as tk

#making main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Encryptor")
root.geometry("600x300")

#getting text
def getting_Text():
    user = text.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    #I print it just to know if the programme work
    print (user)
    if text[0] == "a":
       result.insert(tk.END, ';', 'big') 
    if text[0] == "b":
       result.insert(tk.END, "%", "big")
    #etc.
#UX of the window
prawy_margines = tk.Frame(root)
prawy_margines.pack (side=tk.RIGHT, expand =tk.YES , fill=tk.BOTH)
left_margin = tk.Frame(root)
left_margin.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
#after clicking button function getting_text() is used
button = tk.Button( root , text = "Encrypt", activebackground = "#FFFFFF", command=getting_Text)
button.pack( side = tk.TOP )
text=tk.Text(root, width=36, height=15 )
text.pack(side= tk.LEFT)
result= tk.Text(root, width=36, height=15 )
result.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: replace `if text == "a"` with `if text[0] == "a"`

Comment: Did you mean `if user == 'a':`? or `user[0]` ?

Comment: Mate. The code doesn't work. It display the value that I enter into the terminal even without encryption.

Comment: Use Entry instead of Text widget.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav yes its print your value because i want it to, because i didnt know if it works properly and get the text. It's 11 line and its /// print(user) and you can delete it

Comment: @CoolCloud could you help me with another question i have asked you seem to be an expert greeting from advance

Comment: @thethiny could you help me i have another problem

Comment: Which question?

Comment: @CoolCloud its in my post i have edited it

Comment: You have to post the entire error code please.

Comment: yeah i added the entire error

Comment: Well oops. I didn't read thencode thoroughly. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to seperate a string into single letters is just get everything in your text widget. Then get the length of the string and then creata a loop which uses the first element of the string and put it somewhere you want to save the letters, then remove it from the string and end the loop.

Since it will loop as often as the length of the string you can always just use the first letter of the string and remove it until the string is empty and the loop will end because the length you set for the loop to run ends the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

This may cause error `text` as variable and `text` as widget. Should replace `text` with `user`.

I have two options, with or without Walrus.

- Add `result.delete` on lines 14 and 18. This will be deleted and vice versa.

Without Warlus:

```
def getting_Text():
    user = text.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    #I print it just to know if the programme work
    print (user)
    if user  == "a":
       result.delete('1.0', tk.END) 
       result.insert(tk.END, ';', 'big' )
        
    if user  == "b":
       result.delete('1.0', tk.END)  
       result.insert(tk.END, "%", "big" )
```

With Warlus Python 3.8:

```
def getting_Text():
    if (user := text.get("1.0",'end-1c')) == "a":
        print (user)
        result.delete('1.0', tk.END) 
        result.insert(tk.END, ';' )
        
    elif (user := text.get("1.0",'end-1c')) == "b":
       result.delete('1.0', tk.END)  
       result.insert(tk.END, "%" )
```

Screenshot:
[image]